# Apex Cpu limit exceed error in future method

Tags: apex, future

This future method give me cpu limit error.Using this future method i get the parent account Id and using that fetch the child account and rename it.can anybody help me?

```
   @Future
private static void renameAcctsinHier(String parentId, String oldName, String newName) {
    List<Id> allIds = new List<Id> () ;
    List<Id> parentIds = new List<Id> () ;
    parentIds.add (parentId);
    Account [] accts = [SELECT Id,Name,ParentId FROM Account WHERE ParentId IN :parentIds ORDER BY ParentId, Name] ;
    while (accts.size() > 0) {
        parentIds.clear() ;

        for (Account a : accts) {
            parentIds.add (a.Id) ;
            allIds.add (a.Id) ;
        }
        accts = [SELECT Id,Name,ParentId FROM Account WHERE ParentId IN:parentIds ORDER BY ParentId] ;
    }
    Account [] allAccts ;
    try {
        allAccts = [SELECT Id,Name FROM Account WHERE Id IN :allIds FOR UPDATE];
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.debug ('lock error:' + ex.getMessage()) ;

    }
    for (Account a : allAccts) {
        a.Name = a.Name.replace(oldName, newName);
    }
    update allAccts;
}
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything particularly egregious here, so we'll need more information to be able to give you any real suggestions. How deep is your account hierarchy? How many queries do you end up running? How many Accounts do you end up trying to update? Do you have any triggers on Account? How about any Process Builders or Flows? How long is it taking for you to acquire the lock on all of those records (you should use the Analysis view on a debug log in the developer console to help you answer that)? This is all information you should add to your question by making an [edit].

Comment: About the only suggestion I can give with the information you've given us right now is that `@future` isn't the best approach, and that if you end up working on a sufficient number of records, you'll probably want to update them one layer at a time (instead of all at once). Using the `Queueable` interface instead of the `@future` annotation is likely going to be part of the solution.

Comment: Hi Derek,Thank you for the information. In our org we have few process builders and a flow running on account. I here we are having 3 hierarchy, and whole account record count is 172. I'll try with queueable and update this.

Comment: This seems to include a query in a loop (a while loop in this case) which could be problematic. It also performs the first query with an empty parentIds list. Can you perhaps explain what you are actually trying to do? Just [edit] the question to add such detail.

Comment: @PhilW This is actually one of the few queries in a loop that is (probably) ok. It starts at the root of the hierarchy (the parentId passed in does go into `parentIds` prior to the query) and works itself down one level at a time.

Comment: I would collect the whole hierarchy (with max depth) in one go using field paths in the query if possible to avoid this. If you support arbitrary depths you may hit SOQL query limits. Supporting at most 5 levels will fit in a single query.